# JS Event connected to HTML is not functioning

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following fiddle scripts which I implemented in my website

https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/n4mKw/

Unfortunately when I have applied them, they do not function for example the "quotes" are not changing as they are in the fiddle.

below is the codes I have used in my website

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="./js/event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and the "quotes" script, bit modified by me

```
<div class="quotes">
<li>Version: 99.62T</li>
<li>Drop: 99%</li>
<li>Exp: 7500x</li>
<li>Status: <font color="green">ONLINE</font></li>
</div>
<div class="quotes">
<li>Accounts: 12,889</li>
<li>Characters: 15,349</li>
<li>Guilds: 345</li>
<li>Online Users: 245</li>
</div>
```

also [Here](https://romanesc.uk) is the website and you can see how the quotes are acting on it.

Can someone help me out? thanks.

P.S: I am a begginer on this, so can you please dumb it down for me? :)

Comment: Why are you using `li` as a child of a `div` ? And it is not 1998, do not use font tag.

Comment: to keep the "design" of the little circle showing in front of the text

Comment: *"The HTML <li> element is used to represent an item in a list. It must be contained in a parent element: an ordered list (<ol>), an unordered list (<ul>), or a menu (<menu>)."* [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)

Comment: Please open the developer tools with F12 and tell us if there are any errors

Comment: Use your developer tools! `event.js:30 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at change (event.js:30)`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element

Comment: sorry guys, i have no idea what you are talking about, pressed f12 but i dont know how to use this ..

Comment: @LeLennyZ it's fine just take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2):

Your script is executing before the div has beed loaded, so put this `<script src="./js/event.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` after this `<div id="changeText"></div>` or encapsulate your JavaScript code inside a:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Your logic
}
```

Comment: its still not working

Comment: Press F12 and tell me what appears in the console tab

Comment: it's ok now, i have used your code and the guy's code from below and it seems to work now, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your function like this to executed when elements are available. And need to add interval to your function call to call it every 2 seconds.

```
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(1000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  setInterval(showNextQuote(),2000);

})();
```

Comment: `var inst = setInterval(change, 2000);` that is very dirty

Comment: sorry guys, please ignore the changeText div, as it's a mistake which i forgot to delete from there, the previous answers did not work, any ideas on the code i have provided ?

Comment: Well this code should work its from your code and I tested it on the devtools. What is the problem?

Comment: this is my event.js

$(document).ready
(function() {

  var quotes = $(".quotes");
  var quoteIndex = -1;

  function showNextQuote() {
    ++quoteIndex;
    quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
      .fadeIn(2000)
      .delay(1000)
      .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
  }

  showNextQuote();

})();

Comment: I have edited the answer for you and please provide your code content in the question so people can see the code.

Comment: thanks! used your code and from the other answer above, and seems to be working, appreciate!